# Regular Expression in XML Schema

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

EDIT: I've tried the recommended regular expression in the id attribute, but am now getting the following error when I try to validate the XSD file: "Error at line 7: Element schema has extra content: element"

Here is the code in question:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:patterrn value="[X|Y][0-9]{3}"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
```

If I switch it back to the following code it validates just fine:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
```

Full XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<presentations xmlns="http://www.brett.com/presentations"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.brett.com/presentations presentations.xsd"
>

  <presentation date="2013-07-31" length="PT30M">
    <topic genre="Music">PianoML</topic>
    <presenters>
      <name title="Mr." id="Y258">
        <first>Elvis</first>
        <middle>A</middle>
        <last>Presley </last>
      </name>
      <name title="Miss" id="X365">
        <first>Lady</first>
        <last>Gaga</last>
      </name>
    </presenters>
  </presentation>

    <presentation date="2013-08-05" length="PT35M">
    <topic genre="Science">AlienML</topic>
    <presenters>
         <name title="Mr." id="Y007">
        <first>Will</first>
        <last>Smith</last>
      </name>
      <name title="Mr." id="Y360">
        <first>Tommy</first>
        <first>Lee</first>
        <last>Jones</last>
      </name>
    </presenters>
  </presentation>
</presentations>
```

Full XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://www.brett.com/presentations"
targetNamespace="http://www.brett.com/presentations"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="presentations">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="presentation"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="presentation">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="topic"/>
        <xs:element ref="presenters"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:duration" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="topic">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="genre" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ART"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Science"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Technology"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="presenters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="name">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element ref="first"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:element ref="middle"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="last"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <!-- New changes -->
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:patterrn value="[X|Y][0-9]{3}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="title" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Mr."/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Mrs."/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Ms."/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Miss"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element name="middle" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I noticed that pattern is misspelled.  Is that part of the problem?  `<xs:patterrn value="[X|Y][0-9]{3}"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expressions in XSD's is slightly different, there is a nice article about it here [XML Schema Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html)

> Particularly noteworthy is the complete absence of anchors like the caret and dollar, word boundaries, and lookaround. XML schema always implicitly anchors the entire regular expression. The regex must match the whole element for the element to be considered valid

What you want is as below.

```
        <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[X|Y][0-9]{3}" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
```

Answer for after EDIT:
Below is what you need, note that the xs:ID is on the restriction and not the attribute.

```
  <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
        <xs:pattern value="[X|Y][0-9]{3}" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
```

Comment: My XML and XSD file is now posted above

Comment: Looks like my comment was deleted. This code didn't quite work. Caused a new error that I mention above. If you can still help I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you so much! Got both problems fixed now. Much appreciated!